# unconfirmed btc transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

im using bitcoin classic as a wallet and I've never had a problem before. I sent 1.8 btc over an hour ago and it's still unconfirmed. It's also not showing up on the blockchain..

https://blockchain.info/address/1787Dwi6a8p8yoNHYWBxe8fC337ssD1S4e

any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: Looks resolved.

Comment: If you need faster confirmations use Doge or other altcoin. BTC by design have long confirmation times and is a bit overcrowded nowadays with its 1MB blocks.

Comment: @JakubJagiełło or he could just pay an appropriate fee.

Answer (score 0):

According to [BC.i's info page on the transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/8a3b7e09e075c7a81dc155f638c6648096c62773e93ff9416fb573414f4f7afc) it was mined 7 minutes after they first saw it. One of two things occurred: either your transaction didn't propagate fast enough (eg. you had poor connectivity when broadcasting it, maybe only to Classic nodes or something) or BC.i only saw it late, just before it was mined.